# Kernel mode in multithreaded program

Tags: linux, unix

If a thread in a process makes system call then in uni-threaded process, process will switch o kernel mode. But what will in case of multi-threaded process?
In other words, if a thread in a process makes system call then what is mode of the process which contains that thread -- kernelmode/user mode?

Comment: The thread which makes the system call will transition to kernel mode.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux a thread is simply a process that happens to share memory with several other processes (other threads within the same process).

So, the CPU will be system mode during the syscall, but the execution will still switch to some other thread or process when its time slice expires, just like it normally switches from process to process even if the currently running process is executing a syscall.